# Showing ActivityIndicator while loading page after shelling

Tags: shell, maui

I have the following situation.

On the Login page I have

```
private async Task LoginAsync()
{
    ...............
    IsBusy = true;
    ...............
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Pending)}");
    ..............
    finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
}
```

So I'm shelling from Login to Pending.

In Pending.xaml::

```
<ActivityIndicator
        x:Name="isVeryBusy"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

In Pending xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            LoadData(viewModel);
        }
        .............           
    }
```

and

```
public static async void LoadData(Pending_VM viewModel)
    {
        await viewModel.GetMyObjects();
    }
```

and finally, in the Pending's ViewModel, I have:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task GetMyObjects()
{
    if (IsBusy)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {           
        IsBusy = true;
        //Some slow running code goes here (about three secs)           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;                
    }
}
```

What I would like to do here is to show the ActivityIndicator spinning until my Data Loading is done.

But it doesn't work this way. I stare at the Login page, which seems to be frozen, for about three secs, an then, boom, the Pending page shows up, fully furnished.

What should I do here to show the ActivityIndicator while shelling to another page ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `await` for the async method. Such as:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await LoadData(viewModel);
        }
        .............           
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, but... You see, the task which is taking a long time (3...4 seconds) is in the function LoadData in Pending.OnAppearing, but I am navigating to Pending from Login, so Pending does not show until LoadData returns, so therefore the user is stuck on the Login screen in the meantime. And Login does not know anything about LoadData. So I should execute LoadData NOT in OnAppearing, because this prevents the screen Pending from Appearing, but from another event executing AFTER Pending has already shown. I am afraid that I have not understood this part :-(

Comment: If you used `await LoadData(viewModel)`, it will not stuck the onappearing method and the pending page should show quickly.  @Alex

Comment: Or you can also try to show the ActivityIndicator in the Login Page and hide it after the Pending page's onappearing method finished. @Alex